# With a simple Rich Text control in an XPage how do I limit it's height?

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino, richtext

I'm trying to understand in an Xpage, with a Rich text control, where I would set

config.resize_enabled=false

to stop the rich text editor increasing in size, when someone enters data.

This is Domino 9.0.1 with Fix Packs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm normally a fan of the [max-height](//caniuse.com/#search=max-height) CSS property, but since the height is being set via the JS of the CKEditor, it's better to add a dojo property of *removePlugins* for *autogrow* to the *xp:inputRichText*.

```
<xp:inputRichText
    id="inputRichText1"
    value="#{document1.Body}">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute
            name="removePlugins"
            value="autogrow">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

[Edit]
Here's an update to show that this technique I outlined *does work*. This is from 9.0.1.
[image]
[/Edit]

Comment: @Carl I verified what I outlined works. If there's something more uniquely specific to what you're doing, by all means update your post with some code so it can be reviewed; the more specific the better.

Comment: Thank you @Eric I still have the same issue, I wonder if it is not working for me as I have it in a tabbed table?  Here's an animated gif showing how it doesn't work for me, although the setting is coming through to the HTML Source.
http://www.epilio.com/web/resizeimage.htm/$file/RichTextResize.gif

Comment: @Carl, I've run into some issues with an _xp:inputRichText_ inside a Tabbed Panel before. It's been a while since I've put one into a Tabbed Panel (to avoid what I ran into before), but are you using partialExecute or partialRefresh with your Tabbed Panel?

Comment: I'm using whatever the default is for a Tabbed Panel.  I'll take it out of a Tabbed Panel and see what happens.

Comment: @Carl, how was it outside the Tabbed Panel?

Comment: exactly the same Eric. I even created a brand new page, with just the rich text and nothing else, the size still grows.  I even cut and pasted your code exactly, same thing.

Comment: I just found that autogrow sample page doesn't work in my browser either...

http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/plugins/autogrow/autogrow.html

Comment: @Carl I suspect something may be unique about your browsing environment. What browsers have you tried and have you tried browsing in incognito/private mode to eliminate add-ons or extensions?

Comment: Hi @Eric, I've tried different networks, different browsers, different browser version, emptied caches, same results.  No plugins on the browser, clean browsers.

Comment: @Carl Looking at your gif above, you have two xp:this.dojoAttrbutes tag blocks and an xp:this.attrs block inside an xp:this.dojoattributes tag. Try consolidating the two dojoAttributes blocks.

I tried using just the two tags for dojo attributes of config.removePlugins and config.resize_enabled as it showed for you, but those do nothing for me.

Comment: Works for me. What's essential: style="height:555px"

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you don't want the CKEditor to resize when someone enters data that will overflow the height of the editor? Usually this is what the users want: the editor to grow when the user enters content. I don't know this setting but you can tweak the settings with the autogrow extra-plugin:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" value="#{document1.postBody}"
                                htmlFilter="identity" htmlFilterIn="identity">
                                <xp:this.dojoAttributes>

                                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="width" value="900">
                                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbarType" value="Full">
                                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="extraPlugins" value="autogrow">
                                    </xp:dojoAttribute>

                                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="skin">
                                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return @ClientType().equals("Web") ? "BootstrapCK-Skin,/"+database.getFilePath()+"/bscke/" : ""}]]></xp:this.value>
                                    </xp:dojoAttribute>

                                </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                <xp:this.dojoType><![CDATA[#{javascript:return @ClientType().equals("Web") ? "org.openntf.filesilo.CKEDITOR" : ""}]]></xp:this.dojoType>

                            </xp:inputRichText>
```